# field:uid = field:pid bug in TYPO3 v 8.7.x?

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

The output of {field:uid} is the same as {field:pid}

Does anybody know a way how to output the fluid styled content element id
instead of the page uid.
The output of {data.uid} is correct.

Till TYPO3 version 7.6.x the following code worked
Now (TYPO3 8.7.1) the output field:uid = field:pid.

Is it a TYPO3 bug?

```
lib.contentElement.settings.media.popup.linkParams.ATagParams.dataWrap = class="lightbox" data-fancybox-group="lightbox-{field:uid}" title="{file:current:title}"
lib.contentElement.settings.media.popup.linkParams.ATagParams.dataWrap.insertData = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this: `{file:current:uid_foreign}`

Hope it helps you.